# how to add support for angular app for all safari browsers? Currently webpack errors are generated like Unexpected token 'const'

Tags: angular, angular2-webpack-starter

Does any one knows about this ? My app is working fine on Chrome,Firefox, IE but now working on Safari browsers.....
Safari browser raises error below are the errors

Webpack error on safari browser =>

1. SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const' in vendor.bundle.js:102174
2. TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'modules[moduleId].call') in inline.bundle.js:55

Does any one know how to add support for safari browsers old and new version both for es6??? or how to solve these errors

Comment: one of your libraries uses es6 and does not transform it to es5 / you attach a wrong file to your bundle. Find and fix this and your issue will be solved

Comment: Ok great!! But how to find where this es6 reference is getting attached. So that i can remove it or how to debug or make es6 transformable to es5

Answer (score 1):

you can use [babel transpiler](https://babeljs.io/) for that, check this https://shinesolutions.com/2015/07/07/es6-with-babel-js/

```
npm install --save-dev babel-loader babel-core babel-preset-env webpack
and inside your webpack config:
module: {
 rules: [
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      presets: ['env']
    }
  }
}
]
}
```

Comment: Babel sounds great but how to integrate it with angular 2 any idea can you help me out.

Comment: use babel-load on webpack.config.js

Comment: Ok Thanks. I will try and let you know.

Comment: I have tried the above code. Where to add the module code [ ]? where can i get the webpack config  ? Do I need to install webpack module using npm ? i am new with webpack.... How to use webpack ?

Comment: I found webpack in node_modules but not getting how to use and webpack.dev.js, webpack.prod.js and webpack.config.js ??? I am using angular 2.